# Pass Code To Function Be Executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering is this possible with JavaScript or using JQuery?

I would like to pass in the parameters to a function some code, which it will then execute once other conditions are met.

Comment: Can understand your question, some code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the code to be executed as a function object, like:

```
function executeCode(condition, code) {
    if (condition) code();
}

executeCode(true, function() { alert('executed'); });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I came up with, I cant answer my own question though so you get the points :)

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. You can pass them around in variables just like arrays and anything else.

The tricky bit is "once other conditions are met" since it depends on what those conditions are.

You can either [listen for an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), or you can fake it by polling with `setInterval`.

```
var bar = false;

function doWhenBarIsTrue(func) {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (bar) { 
            clearInterval(interval);
            func(); 
        }
    }, 1000);
}

doWhenBarIsTrue(function () { alert('true!'); });

setTimeout(function () { bar = true; }, 3000);
```

Comment: Sorry I should clarify by other conditions met I just meant I'd have some things like if statements in the function to test a few things before calling it.